# Arduino char *name from string

Tags: c, string, char, arduino

Ok, so I'm making a little song player, and it plays using RTTTL "char*"s

```
char *song = "smb:d=4,o=5,b=100:16e6,16e6,32p,8e6,16c6,8e6,8g6,8p,8g,8p,8c6,16p,8g,16p,8e,16p,8a,8b,16a#,8a,16g.,16e6,16g6,8a6,16f6,8g6,8e6,16c6,16d6,8b,16p,8c6,16p,8g,16p,8e,16p,8a,8b,16a#,8a,16g.,16e6,16g6,8a6,16f6,8g6,8e6,16c6,16d6,8b,8p,16g6,16f#6,16f6,16d#6,16p,16e6,16p,16g#,16a,16c6,16p,16a,16c6,16d6,8p,16g6,16f#6,16f6,16d#6,16p,16e6,16p,16c7,16p,16c7,16c7,p,16g6,16f#6,16f6,16d#6,16p,16e6,16p,16g#,16a,16c6,16p,16a,16c6,16d6,8p,16d#6,8p,16d6,8p,16c6";
```

This one for example plays the theme song of mario. What I'm trying to do is to get a string that i receive and then store it in a char* like these, so it can play. How would i do this conversion?

Comment: What do you mean, `to get a string that i receive` ? How do you receive it ?

Comment: I receive it by serial
`String serial_str()
{
    String content ="";
   char character;

  while(Serial.available()) {
      character = Serial.read();
      content.concat(character);
      delay(10);
  }

  if (content != "") {
    return(content);
  }
}`

Comment: That (your comment) is not C code...what language is that?

Comment: It's called Wiring, an adapted version is used on the Arduino IDE, it has great similarities with C though http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

Comment: Why not just use `String.toCharArray()`?

Comment: I'm trying that out, but as music lenght varies i might have a problem
with the _len_ parameter. http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray

Comment: I'm getting this error now
`sketch_jul18c.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_jul18c:44: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
sketch_jul18c:45: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`

Comment: Can you include all of your source code?  That would be really helpful for figuring out errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it so happens while reviewing my code after a long time I discovered the problem to be in my parsing function applied to the data received from the serial. There was garbage coming in from the serial comms that I wasn't filtering and thus blowing stuff up.